# How to click on <li> elements and automatically check/uncheck form elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

**Target**

My target is that when I click on `<li>` element (which is the element of each answer), the input checkbox inside select or deselect.

I have this **index.html** page:

```
<h3 aria-label="Questions">Questions:</h3>

<form method="POST" action="/submit">
    
    <ul class="list-group mt-3">
        <li class="list-group-item question-item">
            <p class="question-text">What are the primary colors?</p>
            <div class="question" id="3">
                <input type="hidden" name="first_modified_3"
                    id="first_modified_3" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="last_modified_3"
                    id="last_modified_3" value="">
                <ul class="answer-list">
                    
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="What are the primary colors?"
                                value="Red" id="Red">
                            <span>Red</span>
                            </input>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="What are the primary colors?"
                                value="Green" id="Green">
                            <span>Green</span>
                            </input>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="What are the primary colors?"
                                value="Blue" id="Blue">
                            <span>Blue</span>
                            </input>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="What are the primary colors?"
                                value="Yellow" id="Yellow">
                            <span>Yellow</span>
                            </input>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
```

**What I have done**

At the end of `index.html`, before the closing `body` and `HTML` tag, I inserted this script snippet. It works strangely, so all the answers are selected when I click on `<li>` element.

```
$(".list-group-item").click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
        checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked")).change();
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of a `span` use a `label` (with `for` attribute). No need for javascript

Comment: `</input>` is invalid. An input does not have a closing tag.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Nice @Reyno, I solved with your answer (comment).                             <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="What are the primary colors?"
                                        value="Red" id="Red">
                                    <label for="Red">Red</label>
                                    </input>
                            </li>

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried writing the script code that you can find in the section "What I have done"

Comment: Nest your `<input type='checkbox'` *inside* a `<label>` then you don't need `for=` nor any superfluous IDs:  `<label><input type='checkbox'>click me</label>` - depends on your layout requirements - if you already have `id=` or you don't want your labels and checkboxes next to each other, then use `label for=`